# mongoose simple find query failing to fetch result

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

In my collection I have documents like:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectID("5725290dacb36ae775e25dbe"),
    "prop": {
        "giver_name": "Random Tester",
        "giver_id": ObjectID("56b5e87e1827640215c5c055"),
        "giver_url": "random-tester"
    },
    "owner": ObjectID("568fbeef9823be8e105afa46"),
    "title": "testing",
    "content": "hgj jhj hgjh gjhgjhgj hgjhg jhg",
    "type": "recommendation",
    "modified": ISODate("2016-04-30T21:52:13.517Z"),
    "created": ISODate("2016-04-30T21:52:13.518Z"),
    "privacy": {
        "all": true
    },
    "shares": [],
    "interests": [],
    "comments": 0,
    "acknowledgements": [],
    "__v": 0
}
```

I am trying to fetch the above document with a mongoose query

```
Post.findAsync({type:'recommendation','prop.giver_id':"56b5e87e1827640215c5c055" }).then(function(count, err){
    console.log('Recommendation count: ',count," : ",userId," : ",err);
    return res.status(200).json(count);
  });
```

The above query gives me a blank result set, however if I remove the `prop.giver_id` part, I get all the results. I know that field is an `ObjectId` but as far as I have seen, a string in the find query works pretty well. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @JohnnyHK  thanks, I forgot to define that field as objectId in the model. Please post it as an answer so that I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose will cast the fields in your query based on your schema definition, so when a query like this doesn't work, it's often because the schema definition doesn't match your actual document.

In this case ensure `giver_id` is defined in the schema as:

```
giver_id: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId
```